# What do I do about a FORTRAN intrinsic that was not part of the standard?

Tags: fortran, legacy, gfortran, intrinsics

I'm trying to get a legacy FORTRAN code working by building it from source using gfortran.  I have finally been able to build it successfully, but now I'm getting an out-of-bounds error when it runs.  I used gdb and traced the error to a function that uses the loc() intrinsic.  When I try to print the value of `loc(ae)`, with ae being my integer value being passed, I get the error "No symbol "loc" in current context."  I tried compiling with ifort 11.x and debugged with DDT and got the same error.  To me, this means that the compiler knows nothing of the intrinsic.

A little reading revealed that the loc intrinsic wasn't part of the F77 standard, so maybe that's part of the problem.  I posted the definition of the intrinsic below, but I don't know how I can implement that into my code so loc() can be used.

Any advice or am I misinterpreting my problem?  Because both gfortran and ifort crash in the same place due to an out of bounds error, but the function utilizing loc() returns the same large number between both compilers.  It seems a bit strange that loc() wouldn't be working if both compilers shoot back the same value for loc.

> Usage:
>
> iaddr = loc(obj)
>
> Where:
>
> obj
>       is a variable, array, function or subroutine whose address is wanted.
>   iaddr
>       is an integer with the address of "obj". The address is in the same
>   format as stored by an LARn
>   instruction.
>
> Description:
>
> LOC is used to obtain the address of
>   something. The value returned is not
>   really useful within Fortran, but may
>   be needed for GMAP subroutines, or
>   very special debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Well, no, the fact that it compiles means that `loc` *is* known by the compiler; the fact that gdb doesn't know about it just means it's just not known by the debugger (which probably doesn't know the `matmult` intrinsic, either).

`loc` is a widely-available non-standard extension.  I hate those.  If you want something standard that should work everywhere, [c_loc](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_loc), which is part of the C<->Fortran interoperability standard in Fortran2003, is something you could use.  It returns  a pointer that can be passed to C routines.

How is the value from the loc call being used?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Further investigation showed me loc probably isn't the problem.  I have 2 versions of the code built with Compaq VF 6.1, one ignores the 'array out of bounds' error and one stops running because of it.  I made the project settings exactly the same but the behavior continues.  I can't figure this one out and may just have to move to windows and use the pre-existing executable that is functioning.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Gfortran loc seems to work a bit differently with arrays to that of some other compilers. If you are using it to eg check for array copies or such then it can be better to do loc of the first element loc(obj(1,1)) or similar. This is equivalent to what loc does I think with intel, but in gfortran it gives instead some other address (so two arrays which share exactly the same memory layout have different loc results).